# How do I properly set up a webhook endpoint API to handle RevenueCat events with Firebase Functions?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, revenuecat

I'm having trouble setting up a webhook endpoint API directly from [RevenueCat's documentation](https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/firebase).

My code is almost exactly like from the documentation so I don't know why this error is being triggered, and I'm not experienced enough with this kind of stuff to fix the issue. Here is the error I'm getting:

```
(parameter) res: functions.Response<any>

Argument of type '(req: Request, res: Response<any>) => Response<any> | Promise<void | Response<any>>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(req: Request, resp: Response<any>) => void | Promise<void>'.
  Type 'Response<any> | Promise<void | Response<any>>' is not assignable to type 'void | Promise<void>'.
    Type 'Response<any>' is not assignable to type 'void | Promise<void>'.
      Type 'Response<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<void>': then, catch, finally, [Symbol.toStringTag]ts(2345)
```

Honestly, I'm not sure what its asking me to change. Any ideas?
And here is my code:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import { PubSub } from '@google-cloud/pubsub'

const pubsubClient = new PubSub({projectId: '<PROJ_ID>'})

function isAuthorized(req: functions.https.Request) { 
    // Check authorization header
    if (!req.headers.authorization || !req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')) { 
        return false
    }

    const authToken = req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1]
    if (authToken !== '<MY_AUTH_TOKEN>') { 
        return false
    }

    return true
}

// Respond to incoming message
export const revenueCatApi = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => { // *** ERROR DETECTED HERE

    // Only allow POST request
    if (req.method !== 'POST') { 
        return res.status(403).send('Forbidden')
    }

    // Make sure the auth key matches what we set in the Revenue Cat dashboard
    if (!isAuthorized(req)) { 
        return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized')
    }

    const rc = req.body as RCEvent
    var topic: RCTopic = ''

    switch (rc.event.type) { 
        case 'INITIAL_PURCHASE':
            topic = 'rc-initial-purchase'
            break
        case 'NON_RENEWING_PURCHASE':
            topic = 'rc-non-renewing-purchase'
            break
        case 'RENEWAL':
            topic = 'rc-renewal'
            break
        case 'PRODUCT_CHANGE':
            topic = 'rc-product-change'
            break
        case 'CANCELLATION':
            topic = 'rc-cancellation'
            break
        case 'BILLING_ISSUE':
            topic = 'rc-billing-issue'
            break
        case 'SUBSCRIBER_ALIAS':
            topic = 'rc-subscriber-alias'
            break
        default:
            console.log('Unhandled event type: ', rc.event.type)
            return res.sendStatus(200)
    }

    // Set the pub/sub data to the event body
    const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(rc))

    // Publishes a message
    return pubsubClient.topic(topic)
        .publish(dataBuffer)
        .then(() => res.sendStatus(200))
        .catch(err => { 
            console.error(err)
            res.sendStatus(500)
            return Promise.reject(err)
        })
})

exports.handleInitialPurchase = functions.pubsub
    .topic('rc-initial-purchase')
    .onPublish(async (message, context) => {
        ...
    })

/* Other pubsub functions below */
```

RCEvent:

```
interface RCEvent { 
    api_version: string
    event: { 
        aliases: string[]
        app_id: string
        app_user_id: string
        country_code: string
        currency: string
        entitlement_id: string
        entitlement_ids: string[]
        environment: string
        event_timestamp_ms: number
        expiration_at_ms: number
        id: string
        is_family_share: boolean
        offer_code?: string
        original_app_user_id: string
        original_transaction_id: string
        period_type: string
        presented_offering_id: string
        price: number
        price_in_purchased_currency: number
        product_id: string
        purchased_at_ms: number
        store: string
        subscriber_attributes: any
        takehome_percentage: number
        transaction_id: string
        type: string
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that TypeScript has determined that the signature of your function is this:

```
(req: Request, res: Response<any>) => Response<any> | Promise<void | Response<any>>
```

That means it takes a Request and Response as arguments, and can return either one of `Response<any>` or `Promise<void | Response<any>>`.  That's not compatible with the requirement that it return only `void` or `Promise<void>`.

Your function possibly returns three things:

```
return res.status(403).send('Forbidden')

return res.status(401).send('Unauthorized')

return pubsubClient.topic(topic)
```

The first two things you are not really trying to return.  You are just trying to send a response and end early.  The third thing is a promise.

Don't return the result of `res.status(403).send('Forbidden')`.  Just return null if you want to terminate the function early without doing any further work.

```
res.status(403).send('Forbidden')
return null
```

Do this for both of the returns where you have no promise to wait on.  This will make your function state that it only returns a promise or null, which is compatible with the TypeScript requirements for the function.

Comment: The error was still shown with `return null`, so I simply just did `return`, and that seems to have fixed it. Either way, thanks so much Doug!